# SVG embedding not working after Libreoffice upgrade from 3.6 to 4

Tags: windows-7, svg, libreoffice-writer

I used LibreOffice 3.6 to create some documents with some SVG images (insert -> image).
When I open now these documents in LibreOffice 4, the SVG images are not shown.
Is there some bug in LibreOffice 4?
Can you reproduce it?

I also tried to create a new empty document and insert the SVG image but the image still isn't visible after inserting.

Edit: Seems to be a bug in LO4: https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60471

Really annoying =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just re-checked the bug report, and this problem is now marked *RESOLVED FIXED*, and has been released to LibreOffice 4.0.0.3. Please update your installation of LibreOffice.

Comment: Or LibreOffice 4.0.1 =)